# Django: How to add query params to queryset as is done in Pagination?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Our site is DRF backend, with Vue frontend.  It incorporates extensive filter options, so any endpoint could have many query parameters - like `example.com?name__icontains=bob&...etc.`

We have a situation on one view where we need to return a sum of one column. Instead of creating a separate endpoint for the frontend to hit, we want to add it to the results of the original view.  Like so...

```
{
    "pagination": {
        ...pagination stuff...
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "task": "DMSD-50",
            ...other fields...,
            "duration": 204
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "task": "DMSD-53",
            ...other fields...,
            "duration": 121
        },
        ...more rows...
    ],
    "totals": {
        "duration": 955
    }
}
```

My first attempt was to add this to the `get()` method of the view:

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        totals = queryset.aggregate(total_duration=Sum('duration'))
        response['totals'] = {
            'duration': totals['total_duration'] or 0
        }
        return response
```

...which worked when I did the full (unfiltered) list.  But when I added filters in the URL, the total was always the same.  That made me realize that `get_queryset()` doesn't add query parameters from the URL.  I then realized that the pagination class must be incorporating query parameters, so my second solution was to add this code to our custom pagination class.  That works, but it seems like a hack.

What's the best way to get the queryset with query parameters already added, or to add them myself?  I know those parameters are available in kwargs, so if (for example) my view only filtered on "name", I could access the filter via `kwargs['name']` - simple.  But, as I said, there can be many filter args, and they certainly vary from one view to another.

If I loop through kwargs, I'm thinking I might be getting other things besides filter args - sort order comes to mind - but I'm guessing there may be others.  I need a fool-proof way of getting ALL filter args and ONLY filter args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using some generic view or are atleast inheriting from `ListModelMixin`. The `get_queryset` method does not do the filtering of the queryset, that task is done by the [`filter_queryset` method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#filter_querysetself-queryset) of the view, hence when you override the `get` method and don't call that method there is no filtering done. Change your code to use it like so:

```
class YourView(generics.ListAPIView):  # Just an assumption here
    ...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        totals = queryset.aggregate(total_duration=Sum('duration'))
        response['totals'] = {
            'duration': totals['total_duration'] or 0
        }
        return response
```

For understanding better exactly how the builtin view works you might want to look at it's [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/e92016ac2e926483e05e296558fc3d1ea3279625/rest_framework/mixins.py#L33-L46).

Comment: That did the trick. I figured there must be a simple method call that would take care of it, I just couldn't find it. Instead of reading the code, I had stepped through in debug, hoping to see where it added those parameters. But I quickly got lost in all the confusing method calls that happen during a request. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create empty context

   ```
   Context = {}
   ```
2. Update context with each existing filter in request.GET

   ```
   If request.GET.get('filter'):

      Context['filter] = request.GET.get('filter')
   ```
3. Add filters to queryset

   ```
   Query.objects.filter(**Context )
   ```

Comment: That would still require hard-coding all the filter keys in the code. It's actually much worse than the simple example in my OP. For some of our TextChoices fields, we might have __exact or __icontains or __in suffixes on the field name. That grows the number of possibilities exponentially. I guess I'll have to do it by exception in a loop. That is, if "ordering" is the only non-filter query param, I'll skip that key value. If others come up at some point, I'll just have to add them to the "skip" list.  I just thought there must be some canned way, if pagination classes handle it.